# Not getting count according to filter in GraphQL amplify queries

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

Getting Scanned count but not count of data according to filter

```
count: null
items: [{id: "bcd75096-7fd9-4e9d-8675-6877f0609ac2", name: "dxfrdhjkhklklkl", description: "dgdxrfg",…},…]
0: {id: "bcd75096-7fd9-4e9d-8675-6877f0609ac2", name: "dxfrdhjkhklklkl", description: "dgdxrfg",…}
1: {id: "52f6ff60-fc07-4631-a1fb-b039f376ff21", name: "ghnfgyhj", description: "gyhkjmuhjolk",…}
2: {id: "f73dfb37-2778-4b87-88c7-e6f9f5b5c931", name: "drftgserty", description: "trse54rte54ty",…}
3: {id: "6df9f5c2-ec06-4e70-b5e2-133cb0d8e958", name: "tygujghukuh", description: "tuyjyuikuolnh",…}
4: {id: "9360a766-ac89-420c-881b-2b3089bcca7f", name: "kl;", description: "vcbghnjmk,l", is_active: true,…}
5: {id: "c0dcbaff-37d4-4e4c-9375-584ff7110d77", name: "dfhgbdcb", description: "dfxvcx", is_active: true,…},...
scannedCount: 100
```

I have followed these tutorials to get count [HOW TO COUNT THE NUMBER OF RESULTS WITH AWS AMPLIFY DYNAMODB AND GRAPHQL](https://www.riccardosirigu.com/blog/aws-amplify-dynamodb-total-count-graphql-queries/)

Filter

```
      var body = {
        filter: {
          is_active: {
            eq: true
          }
        }
      }
```

Query to get list of todos

```
export const listTodos = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListTodos(
    $filter: ModelTodoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      count
      items {
        id
        name
        description
        is_active
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      scannedCount
    }
  }
`;
```

GraphQl shema

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  is_active: Boolean
}

type ModelTodoConnection {
  items: [Todo]
  scannedCount: Int
  count: Int
  total: Int
}
```

And IF I set limit to 5 and it will send back `scannedCount` 5 if when I have total data in database around 110. I want to count data where   `is_active: { eq: true }`

Comment: Can you share your graphql schema?

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: I do not think DynamoDB is capable of providing accurate result counts for GraphQL queries. Ref: [Total counts in GraphQL queries](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1865) issue on Amplify CLI GitHub repo. I also think both [DynamoDB Query.Count documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Count) and the [referrenced blog post](https://www.riccardosirigu.com/blog/aws-amplify-dynamodb-total-count-graphql-queries/) are misleading in this matter.

Comment: I am trying to get solution from last 4 days but didn't get anything

Comment: Yes, I can see why. The more I read about this the more it seems like counting GraphQL query results is an unsolved problem of DynamoDB. So I do not think there is an out-of-the-box solution for this problem. Still, there are some suggestions in the [issue thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1865) that might be worth a try, if counting GraphQL query results is a mandatory requirement.

Comment: Nearly i have tried all the possible solution but all are useless because they are returning total data count of table when i wont to get data count which fulfill the condition in filter

Comment: When you create Todos table on your schema, with Amplify push appSync generates listTodos, you can call it with any filter and output only ID numbers. Within the app just use length and you'll see the total count.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the package I wrote to solve this issue: https://github.com/multimeric/AmplifyCountDirective.

After following the installation instructions, to solve your issue I would change the schema to this:

```
type Todo @model @count {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  is_active: Boolean
}
```

Then you can query the count using a GraphQL query such as:

```
{
    countTodo(filter: {
        is_active: {
            eq: true
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand...appSync generates listTodo, you can call it with any filter and output only ID numbers. Within the app just use length and you'll see the total count.

Comment: The length of the result array will only tell you how long **one page** of data is. This package and its resolver will return the length of the entire table or query.

Comment: if you set no limit you get all pages at once.

Comment: That is not the case. If your dataset exceeds 1 mb it will be automatically paginated by DynamoDB. There is a reason why [this thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1865) has draw such attention.